# Pass Uri through Intent to MusicService MediaPlayer, from ListView click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

When I pass a URL it works fine (user clicks a button):

```
final Intent i = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_URL);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://stream-72.shoutcast.com:80/hot108_mp3_128kbps");
i.setData(uri);
startService(i);
```

But when the user clicks a ListView item, nothing happens:

```
public List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
}


private void playSong(String songPath) {
    final Intent i = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_URL);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(songPath);
    i.setData(uri);
    startService(i);
}
```

I've tried setting up Toasts in `MusicService.ACTION_URL` and it never gets called only in the ListView scenario but it does in the first button click scenario.

I've even tried creating a local MediaPlayer (outside the Service) inside the playSong method and it works fine, but I want the MusicService to handle playing the list item instead:

```
mp.setDataSource(songPath);
```

Please tell me, what am I doing wrong? If you need more info let me know.
Thanks.

Here is the UPDATED manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Design.streaming"
android:versionCode="56"
android:versionName="1.8.0.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature name="android.hardware.touchscreen" required="false" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>  

    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"> 
</activity>

    <activity android:name=".Blog" android:launchMode="singleTask"     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".Favs" android:launchMode="singleTask"     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".Songs" android:launchMode="singleTask"     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".IcyStreamMeta" />
    <activity android:name=".Favorites"> </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PizzaMain" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Info"/>
    <activity android:name=".SomafmActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerproMain" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
         />
    <activity android:name=".AncientfmActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
         />
    <activity android:name=".Pizza" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResultDeligate" />
    <activity android:name=".AppPreferenceActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
                android:name="net.learn2develop.AppPreferenceActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MusicService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.PLAY" />
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.PAUSE" />
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.SKIP" />
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.REWIND" />
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.STOP" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.Main" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
        </intent-filter> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.URL" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".MusicIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: what is the value of the `songPath` in the `playSong()` method?

Comment: (MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));

Comment: It's passed in from onListItemClicked

Comment: print the value in logcat that method and post here...

Comment: @MikeLudwig : make a log or Toast to check `MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position)` value your are getting right url

Comment: I'm getting this: /mnt/sdcard/AudioStreamSaves/xxx.mp3

Comment: As you said it is working in button click..Do the same in listview click give this("http://stream-72.shoutcast.com:80/hot108_mp3_128kbps") hardcore value in listview click and check whether that song is playing???By this u can conclude the path problem.

Comment: Ok I tested as you suggest and it is playing the URL. I don't understand because I know my local path is correct (as I mention when I use the same path in a local MP it works, but not in my MusicService.

Comment: Hmm i dont know how to troubleshoot since it's working on a local MP...and the MusicService works with a URL.

Comment: I would like to know if anyone else has success with clicking ListView item to pass local Uri to a MusicService???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
private void playSong(String songPath) {
    final Intent i = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_URL);
    File file = new File("file://"+songPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    i.setData(uri);
    startService(i);
}
```

Comment: That's not working; also tried `File file = new File(songPath);` and that didn't work either.

Comment: If anyone has time please veview my MusicService file: [MusicService.java](https://github.com/ludwig1/MusicService/blob/master/.gitignore) It is an adaptation from the Android Samples (Random Music Player). Thank you very much.

Comment: can you share some info about what all method are getting called in MusicService.. is `playNextSong` getting called?... can you check what is the url getting passed to this method.. is there any exception in this method?

Comment: Here's what I don't understand at all: Not even the intents in MusicService are being called; I'm adding Toasts to the starting block in each intent and they do not get called. For example, else `if (action.equals(ACTION_URL))
   processAddRequest(intent);` I'm putting a toast in here and it isn't called, but when a http address is added to the intent it DOES get called. What needs to be in my manifest? (cont...)

Comment: Now I have this in my manifest: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.URL" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>`  Do I need to add or remove something?  The URL won't load if I remove the data tag "http", and I tried adding another "file" tag but that didn't do anything.

Comment: try by also adding data scheme `file`... as per current settings it would only be called for `http` type URL..

Comment: Now the player is going to Error (I have Toast in onError and that is showing).

Comment: playNextSong is getting called; the value of manualUrl is file:///mnt/sdcard.AudioStreamSaves/xxx.mp3...this is after I removed the "file" part of `("file://"+songPath);` because "file" was showing twice in the Uri (the value of manualUrl).

Comment: Written like `("file://"+songPath);` the Uri is file:///file%3A/mnt/sdcard/AudioStreamSaves/xxx.mp3 What is hapening?

Comment: Praful Bhatnagar thank you for all your help!!! You got me in the right direction.